# Checking if function exists

Tags: php

I got an problem with checking i a function exists - i know function_exists() and method_exists() but cannot get the functionality i look for

I pass functions through a socket connection like $MM->Player->Play().
After that i eval them and return the result through the socket connection.

I do filter the functions (have to start with $MM, anything else will be rejected),
but i cant get my code to check if the function exists. This is important because
the server will crash if the function does not exists.

Anyone know a solution for this??

Thanks in advance.

the code:

`$MM = new SDBApplication;`

In the constructor of SDBApplication:

`$this->Player = new SDBPlayer;`

I tried the following methods to check:
the code:

`method_exists($MM, "Player::Play");`
`function_exist("$MM->Player->Play);`

both return false even though the function exists

**The solution**

```
$parts = explode('->', $string);
$numParts = count($parts)-1;
$object = '$MM';
for($i=0; $i < $numParts; $i++){
    $object .= '->'.$parts[$i];
}
$parts[$numParts+1] = preg_replace('(\\(.*\\))', '', $parts[$numParts]);
eval( '$check = method_exists('.$object.', '.$parts[$numParts+1].');');
```

It needs to be eval'd because the input is a string.

Comment: can you show us your code and the errors?

Comment: It's getting late over here so i'll do that first thing tomorow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it this way around in your constructor of `SDBApplication`

```
method_exists($this->Player, 'Play');
```

Comment: That does work. To get the input split up i'll have to use an explode. 

However i do wonder that if someone inputs something like `$MM->DoesNotExists->Play()` it will give me the correct result. I'll test it when i get home.

Comment: Personally if your class relies entirely on that method existing, I'd return false from the constructor if it doesn't exist, or throw an error.

Comment: It is not about the class being loaded, it is about filtering the user input so the server does not crash. But i got it to work, see the original post

Answer (score 2):

[function_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) and [method_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) are for this type of checks. First is for regular functions and second for OOP functions.