# Is there a way to check if a function exists within a class?

Tags: php, function

I'm passing some post data to execute a function based on post data, to determine if this should execute I've tried to use the following:

```
$SP = new StoredProcedure();

if(function_exists($SP->$_POST['function']))
{
    $SP->$_POST['function']();
}
else
{
    echo 'function does not exist.';
}
```

Unfortunately this passes the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: StoredProcedure::$getFormList in
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\junglegym\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\qcore\qcore_waitress.php
>   on line 353 function does not exist.

I'm certain this function does exist, and when I execute it without the `function_exists()`

Is there a way to check if a function exists when it's inside a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`method_exists` checks for method of a class for a given object:

Docs Link:
http://www.php.net/method_exists

```
if(method_exists($SP, $_POST['function'])) {
    {
        $SP->$_POST['function']();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'function does not exist.';
    }
```

`function_exists()` and `method_exists()` are for these checks. First is for regular functions and second for `OOP` functions.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [method_exists](http://www.php.net/method_exists)

Try with:

```
if(method_exists($SP, $_POST['function'])) {
```

Answer (score 2):

check this all

[Find out if a method exists in a static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156593/find-out-if-a-method-exists-in-a-static-class)

[Checking if function exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112297/checking-if-function-exists)

and also PHP manual at

php.net/method_exists

php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

www.php.net/class_exists

Hope these might help you.